# How do I install Jupyter/iPython on Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I want to use [Jupyter/iPython](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) on [Cloud Dataproc](http://cloud.google.com/dataproc). How can I automatically install and configure it when I create new clusters?

Comment: Looks like there are a few votes to close - can anyone extrapolate on anything missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cloud Dataproc team has a [GitHub repository of initialization actions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions) containing sample and often-used initialization actions. There is specifically one for [iPython](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/ipython-notebook) in the repository you can use to automatically install and configure iPython. The [initialization action page](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/init-actions) has more details on how to use the scripts when creating a new cluster.

**The tl;dr process:**

1. [Download](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/ipython-notebook/ipython.sh) the initialization action for iPython
2. Save the initialization action into a Google Cloud Storage bucket
3. [Create a new cluster](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/create-cluster) with the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) using the `--initalization-actions` flag:

   `gcloud beta dataproc clusters create <my-dataproc-cluster> --initialization-actions gs://<my-bucket>/ipython.sh`
4. [Create an SSL tunnel and SOCKS proxy](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces) to the cluster
5. Open a web browser to the master node `http://<my-dataproc-cluster>-m:8123`

In the example above you need to replace `<my-bucket>` with the name of your Cloud Storage bucket and `<my-dataproc-cluster>` with the name of your cluster. Also note that for step #5 the URL should add a `-m` to the name of your cluster so you access your **master node**.

Comment: when I open ```http://<my-dataproc-cluster>-m:8123``` it is asking for password. I didn't set any password. Please help

Comment: The Download li nk in Step 1 doesn't work anymore. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the previous answer, this procedure is described in high detail in the [article](http://blog.sourced.tech/post/dataproc_jupyter). Besides, it covers Python 3 and keeping notebooks in Cloud Storage.